# Problem in Automating SAP using Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

Our team is automating SAP processes using Automation Anywhere. We are using DLL provided by the Automation Anywhere itself and accessing it using metabots. Everytime when the task calls the metabot we are getting the notification "A Script is attempting to access SAP GUI". We tried by disabling the notification options inside the SAP GUI. But after that while running the task, the metabot itself is not working. Below is the simple code for login,

```
Open : "C:\Programs Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogin.exe"
Activate Window : "SAP Logon 740"
Object Cloning:Select Item By Index "1" in windows 'SAP Logon 740';Click Type:Click;Source:Window;Play Type:Object
Run MetaBot "SAPMetabot.Login"(Logic)
```

Can anyone help in this case?

Comment: If you record a SAP macro (vbscript) and run it, does it work?

Comment: Do you want me to run the vbscript which I used to get the Object Id's???

Comment: Yes. If it works, you can be certain that the problem is with AA and not with SAP and move from there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change the settings in your Sap to "allow scripts connect to sap", an the problem should be solved. As SAP is giving you warnings that a script is trying to connect. if the settings are changed, it wont warn.

Answer (score 0):

Trust that you are well.

if i understood you question correctly, your SAP Metabot is not working right ?

When SAP metabot logic works, it must first connect to SAP, ( which means it create a connection with SAP application ) this can be achieved using method inside the dll.

try this and let me know if you are able to resolve this issue.

Regards,

NoSpaceForLove

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Please make sure Automation Anywhere and SAP GUi both running on same mode like Automation Anywhere (Without Run As Admin ) and SAP GUI also running without Run As Admin. or both should be run with admin.
2. Instead of index 1 use index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Enable SAP scripting on SAP GUI and rerun your task.